# Developing a dynamic language

Tags: language-design, dynamic-typing

I have created several hand written compilers for very simple languages but now I want to try my hand at developing a dynamic language, similar to a simplified Python or Ruby.  However, it was easy for me to wrap my head around how compilers work.  Primitive compilers just translate.  But I can't do this if the language is dynamic.  I have to write an interpreter or VM that keeps track of information at runtime and puts a lot more work on me.

In short, are there any resources I should check out considering I know how compilers work but want to migrate to creating an interpreter?  There are a few VMs out there for dynamic languages, but I have no problem with rolling my own.  This is all just for my personal experience.

I am seeking information on how to go from a compiler to an interpreter.  If I have already made a compiler for language X but now what to write an interpreter, what needs to be done and are there any resources that go over the process?

I do not want broad or abstract resources that go over how compilers or virtual machines work.  I have plenty of textbooks on the subject.  All of the resources I found online either assume you have 0 experience and thus start you off with lexical or syntactic analysis or they are extremely abstract.  I have a working compiler, but I now want to turn this into an interpreter and add dynamic features to the language.

I could not find resources on this process, it may be too limited in scope, or resources on the "back end" of an interpreter without being too theoretical which is why I posted here.

Comment: There are tons of resources like this. Note that the line between compiler and interpreter is more blurred than you think it is; the C# 4.0 compiler supports dynamic programming, as do a number of other compilers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, what I am asking is for resources to make my own run time/interpreter/virtual machine.  The .Net interpreter is far too complicated for me to base mine off of!

Comment: [Writing Compilers and Interpreters: A Software Engineering Approach](http://www.amazon.com/Writing-Compilers-Interpreters-Software-Engineering/dp/0470177071/ref=pd_sim_b_6), [(How to Write a (Lisp) Interpreter (in Python))](http://norvig.com/lispy.html), [Virtual Machine Showdown: Stack Versus Registers](http://static.usenix.org/events/vee05/full_papers/p153-yunhe.pdf) (PDF), [The design of the Inferno virtual machine](http://www.vitanuova.com/inferno/papers/hotchips.html), [Parrot: A Virtual Machine For Everyone](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/Parrot-a-Virtual-Machine-For-Everyone)

Comment: And check out this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926835/how-to-write-an-interpreter), there are a couple of comments with references to other questions that are quite interesting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First learn about implementing interpreters. I recommend [PLAI (Programming Languages: Application and Interpretation)](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/). It gets to the meat of interpretation quickly without dwelling overlong on syntax.

For your language, you'll be able to reuse the compiler's front-end (parser, mostly) and run-time library (GC, data structures, primitive operations, etc).

Of course, you can also implement a dynamic language with a compiler that produces code that manipulates (some of) the same data structures that you would use in an interpreter. For example, in an interpreter you might implement global variables as a string-indexed hash table. In a compiler, you would compile global variable references into the code that does the lookup using the same table. In contrast, you could compile lexical variables into a more efficient representation ("native" arguments and closure structure references).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to learn the basics of implementing an interpreter for a dynamic language, I can't imagine a better place to start than the origins of the very first dynamic, interpreted programming language: Lisp.

In his original [1960 paper](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive.pdf), John McCarthy defined 5 primitive functions necessary to a Lisp. Of course, McCarthy only intended his paper on Lisp as an academic exercise; it was a graduate student who implmented `eval` in assembly and created the first Lisp interpreter. Paul Graham [identifies seven primitives](http://www.paulgraham.com/rootsoflisp.html): quote, atom, eq, cons, car, cdr, and cond.

The thing is, you can really implement Lisp in any language; once you implement `eval`, it's easy to set up a REPL, and you have an *interactive* interpreter. People have been bored or curious enough to implement Lisps in C, Java, Ruby, Python, and many other languages. And not always on purpose; it's important to remember [Greenspun's Tenth Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_tenth_rule):

> Any sufficiently complicated C or Fortran program contains an ad hoc, informally-specified, bug-ridden, slow implementation of half of Common Lisp.

I'm not saying your end-goal should be a Lisp implementation; but homoiconicity has its benefits when learning to implement a dynamic language; why deal with syntax issues when you can learn on a language in which the idiomatic syntax is identical toe the AST of a language that uses a lexer/parser?

Anyhow... just a suggestion. But it is with good reason that most of the great programming languages since C have at least a little of the Lisp-nature.

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers.  Thanks, I think I really will implement a Lisp interpreter.  It is easy to parse, has ton of documentation and existing code, and should give me a foundation to work with.  Unfortunately I took an undergraduate class that used Scheme and it made me pull my hair out ;)

Comment: I am now tempted to compile my language into my own dialect of Lisp!

Comment: See also [Lisp in Small Pieces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces)

Answer (score 0):

I've put this (~ 600 lines of C#) in the public domain, which supports quote / list / apply / eval / test / etc, and allows to customize a Lisp-like syntax and/or the semantic builtins easily:

https://repl.it/CdjV/3

E.g.:

```
        var factorial = (Lambda)language.
            Evaluate
            (@"
                ( => ( n ) (
                        ? ( != n 0 )
                        ( * n ( this ( - n 1 ) ) )
                        1
                    )
                )
            ");

        var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        var n = 12;
        var r = 0;
        int k;
        sw.Start();
        for (k = 0; k < 10000; k++)
        {
            r = (int)factorial.Invoke(null, n);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}! = {1}", n, r);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("in {0} ms (for {1} times)", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, k.ToString("0,0"));
```

'HTH,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know a bit of Scheme (e.g. have read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)) or Lisp, I recommend Queinnec's [Lisp In Small Pieces](https://pages.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html) book. It explains several variants of Lisp-like interpreters & compilers (including to bytecode or to C).

Also, read Scott's [Programming Language Pragmatics](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/), the latest [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools#Second_edition), the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/), Pierce's [Types & programming languages](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/).

> I am seeking information on how to go from a compiler to an interpreter.

Then, [partial evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation) (& Futamura projections) and [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) could be relevant.